# Clear Notification Bar Android

Tags: android, notifications

I want to remove the notifications from the notifications bar in Android For a particular application, and not the complete the notification panel.

Right now I am using :

```
public void clearNotification() {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_ID);
}
```

But for this case I have to give the notification id, but there are some cases in my code when notification ID is not known to me.

I just want to clear all the notifications of my PARTICULAR App and the rest of the notifications should remain the same. Is it possible to do the same ???

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, the NotificationManager.cancelAll method should do what you want - cancel all of the notifications that your app has issued, but leave other notifications that you didn't create. I think the Android doc on this method is not that clear. I've not used this specific call but give it a try out when you have other notifications around.